# Force a user to write the first number (html)

Tags: html

I have  a field for phone number but i dont want users to put like +1 but instead to write the local number .
How can i make the number to start with  6?
this is the input :      how can i disable the +1  nor

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Perhaps some examples would make it clearer what you are asking.

Comment: When im commenting this comment, the input field wont let me write words but only input numbers,i want on a input field to start with an number then you can write whatever is needed.

Comment: If you are talking about the new HTML5 `<input type="tel">`, then you can apparently ([according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)) specify a `pattern` attribute, so you could set it to numeric only. Bear in mind that you can't *rely* on the browser actually validating this though, as older or simpler browsers won't have implemented this feature.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understod this correctly then you just might wanna add a `placeholder` as an element to the input, stating the user to type the local number. Another solution might be to add a `value` to the input. Both very simple things to add if it's the desired outcome.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Write local number"/>
<input type="text" value="6"/>
```

Example to the two solutions:
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3MFnV/)

Comment: Like that but i want if user types 4 in the beggining of the form it should alert that the number should start with a 6 then u can put anything you like after it..

Comment: Nevermind,i used a  minimum and maximum to make sure the phone number is correct. thanks

Answer (score -1):

I  used a  minimum and maximum to make sure the phone number is correct. thanks.
so practically is kinnda the same as what i was wanting
This is what i used:

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).